# Firing onItemDisclosure event causes itemtap event to fire

Tags: listview, sencha-touch, extjs, mobile-website

i am trying to handle to events on the same list , the first is the itemtap event and the other is the onItemDisclosure event.

When i tap on the arrow , the onItemDisclosure event is fired and handler is executed , however , the itemtap is fired as well , and after the onItemDisclosure handler executes , the itemtap handler is in turn executed.

How can i solve this ?

View :

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.listview', {   
    requires: [ 'myapp.model.listmodel'],
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    alias:'widget.listview',  
    id : 'listview',
    fullscreen: true,  
config: {

    iconCls: 'list',


    title : 'List',
    onItemDisclosure: function () {
    alert('ok')

    },               

    store:'ListView',  
    itemTpl:'{title}'   


  }
 });
```

Controller Code :

```
 Ext.define('myapp.controller.Main', {  
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views : ['listview'],
    config : {


    refs:{

        list:'#listview'


    },
    control :{



        listview:{
            itemtap:'display',
            onItemDisclosure : 'disclosure'
        }






    }
},


display:function(){
   alert('tap')
},




disclosure:function (){
    alert('disclosure');
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onItemDisclosure` is a property of Ext.List - not an event. In controller's `control`, we use events. So, here you will need **disclose** event similar to "itemtap" event. Check this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-disclose).

Comment: Thanks for correcting me , but still the two events are fired when i click on the arrow.

Comment: This answer does not address the question; moosekebab's does

Answer (score 9):

You need to stop the `itemtap` event continuing to bubble. First you need the arguments to the function call, then on the event argument you call `stopEvent()`.

```
disclosure: function(list, record, node, index, event, eOpts) {
    console.log('disclose');        

    event.stopEvent();
},
```

Comment: Why isn't this the selected answer ?!?